# systemctl start nginx fails

Tags: nginx, webserver, systemctl

Disclaimer: I have 0 server administration experience, so forgive my terminology and apparent lack of effort in describing the issues. I just don't really know what I'm doing.

Anyway, I was following [this article](https://blog.readme.com/auto-generating-ssl-certificates-for-custom-domains-using-lets-encrypt/) to generate SSL certificates automatically which is something we need for our arbitrary domains, which lead me to these [docs](https://github.com/auto-ssl/lua-resty-auto-ssl) to install the
nginx extension that does precisely that. I started going through the requirements section and went ahead to install the first one: [OpenResty](http://openresty.org/en/download.html), which I believe extends nginx modules. I followed the [installation process](http://openresty.org/en/linux-packages.html), ran the initial commands to shut down nginx for the installation to go through:

```
sudo systemctl disable nginx
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

And the installation went fine, but when I try to start nginx up again with

```
sudo systemctl enable nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

I get an error in the last command:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This is what `sudo systemctl status nginx.service` tells you:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-06-19 11:50:25 UTC; 5min ago
  Process: 2160 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2157 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 19 11:50:22 staging nginx[2160]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 19 11:50:23 staging nginx[2160]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 19 11:50:23 staging nginx[2160]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 19 11:50:24 staging nginx[2160]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 19 11:50:24 staging nginx[2160]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 19 11:50:25 staging nginx[2160]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Jun 19 11:50:25 staging systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 19 11:50:25 staging systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Jun 19 11:50:25 staging systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 19 11:50:25 staging systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have no idea how this means or how to solve it. I don't even know what `systemctl` does, honestly. I believe it's some kind of interface for services, but I really don't know. It was just installed when the staging server was set up.

Comment: Just as some background, yes, `systemctl` controls services. `enable` and `disable` just sets a service to start at boot or not. If you want more logs, you can try `journalctl -u nginx`. Usually when this issue happens, you have something else running taking the port like apache2 / httpd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

means that there’s still a running daemon listening on port 80. You can use

```
lsof -i :80
```

to find out what it is. Stop that, and you’ll then be able to start the `nginx` service.

Comment: Killing the process on port 80 solved it. But why would nginx have kept listening after running `disable` and `stop`?

Comment: Did you check that it really was nginx? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/175578/5132